# Abstract class @RestController Spring 4 - @ResponseBody error

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I was doing a abstraction about my CRUD, creating a abstract class with the methods that I needed. Although I've get done it, when I send the requests to insert (POST) and to update (PUT) Spring framework doesn't get convert the <@RequestBody T> for concrete class. Any method called into "createdAction" or "updateAction" doesn't work.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/user")
public class UserWebResource extends AbstractWebResource<UserEntity> { }
```

__

```
public abstract class AbstractWebResource<T extends PersistenceEntity> {

     @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "application/json")
     public ResponseEntity<T> createAction(@RequestBody T dataEntity, HttpSession session) {
        dataEntity = rule.save(dataEntity);

        if (dataEntity.hasErrors()) {
           return new ResponseEntity<T>(dataEntity, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        }

        return new ResponseEntity<T>(dataEntity, HttpStatus.CREATED);
     }

     @RequestMapping(value = "/{id}", method = RequestMethod.PUT, produces = "application/json")
     public ResponseEntity<T> updateAction(@PathVariable("id") Integer id, @RequestBody T dataEntity, HttpSession session) { ... }
}
```

Error POST e PUT

GRAVE: Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcher] in context with path [/app] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: argument type mismatch
HandlerMethod details: 
Controller [br.inf...web.resource.UserWebResource]
**Method [public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity br.inf...web.resource.AbstractWebResource.updateAction(java.lang.String,T,javax.servlet.http.HttpSession)]**

Comment: show your implementations of AbstractWebResource

Comment: it is edited @Cootri

Answer (score 0):

Seems like there is a problem with marshaling framework.

You can't use generic types with Jackson 2.7 & Spring 4.2, you should either roll back Jackson dependency version to 2.6.6 or use Spring 4.3 (when it'll come out).

[source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35322400/spring-mvc-rest-controller-requestbody-parsing)